# What is causing this ClassLoader StackOverflowError when using Apache CXF webclient?

Tags: java, jaxb, cxf

I am encountering a StackOverflowError when tying to use Apache CXF Webclient on my production systems only.

I am using a 32bit jdk1.6.0_26 on 64bit windows 2008.

I thought it might have something to do with Jaxb, but I have checked that I do not have  any version of jaxb-impl on the class path (should be using the JDK one).

Any suggestions on what this might be? Or how I can diagnose it?

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
        at java.util.Vector.addElement(Vector.java:572)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.addClass(ClassLoader.java:166)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
        at org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.SpringBusFactory.createBus(SpringBusFactory.java:102)
        at org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.SpringBusFactory.createBus(SpringBusFactory.java:91)
        at org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.SpringBusFactory.createBus(SpringBusFactory.java:69)
        at org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.SpringBusFactory.createBus(SpringBusFactory.java:58)
        at org.apache.cxf.BusFactory.getDefaultBus(BusFactory.java:99)
        at org.apache.cxf.BusFactory.createThreadBus(BusFactory.java:165)
        at org.apache.cxf.BusFactory.getThreadDefaultBus(BusFactory.java:155)
        at org.apache.cxf.BusFactory.getThreadDefaultBus(BusFactory.java:140)
        at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.AbstractEndpointFactory.getBus(AbstractEndpointFactory.java:83)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.AbstractJAXRSFactoryBean.getBus(AbstractJAXRSFactoryBean.java:89)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.AbstractJAXRSFactoryBean.createEndpointInfo(AbstractJAXRSFactoryBean.java:133)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.AbstractJAXRSFactoryBean.createEndpoint(AbstractJAXRSFactoryBean.java:216)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.JAXRSClientFactoryBean.createWebClient(JAXRSClientFactoryBean.java:195)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient.create(WebClient.java:90)
```

Comment: You can you `jstack` get the current thread stack info.Or, dump the JVM heap use `jmap`.

Comment: Just a guess here, but it sounds like your vector is not large enough to handle what you add to it. It's failing on the add() method call. What size is your vector, did you initialize it? Try to create it with a set size first before you add to it.

Comment: @Logan I don't think that is it, as vectors are held on the heap not the stack in Java. I think its some kind of infinite loop in the ClassLoader (loading a class causing the same class to be loaded again somehow?)

Comment: Oh yeah, I see what you are saying now about that. It does look like some kind of loop. It's hard to say without seeing the code around the call that does this, but are you loading a vector object into a vector? If so, maybe change the object you are loading into the vector to something other than a vector and see if it works.

Comment: @Logan my code is not using vectors at all. The vector is used in the implementation of the Java class loader by sun JVM code. I think that the vector is not very relevant, it just happens to be the place where the stack ran out. I think the problem is the recursive loop between: java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) and java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the threads on my production environment have been configured with a very small stack size, so there genuinely is not enough space to do the recursive class loading. D'oh.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Solved the Problem for me

Comment: Somehow a xss of 128k was set which is too less obsiously (default is 1024k for a 64Bit VM)