# Jmeter - Unknown Error Writing Event

Tags: java, jmeter, stack-overflow

I got an output error while running a JMeter test: `Logging Error: Unknown error writing event.`

I've seen these before but they usually relate to Java being out of memory. However, this time the related error was listed as:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.io.PrintWriter.<init>(PrintWriter.java:116)
    at java.io.PrintWriter.<init>(PrintWriter.java:100)
    at org.apache.log.format.PatternFormatter.getStackTrace(PatternFormatter.java:555)
    at org.apache.log.format.PatternFormatter.formatPatternRun(PatternFormatter.java:472)
    at org.apache.log.format.PatternFormatter.format(PatternFormatter.java:446)
    at org.apache.log.output.AbstractOutputTarget.format(AbstractOutputTarget.java:118)
    at org.apache.log.output.AbstractOutputTarget.doProcessEvent(AbstractOutputTarget.java:77)
    at org.apache.log.output.AbstractTarget.processEvent(AbstractTarget.java:108)
    at org.apache.log.Logger.fireEvent(Logger.java:632)
    at org.apache.log.Logger.output(Logger.java:607)
    at org.apache.log.Logger.output(Logger.java:590)
    at org.apache.log.Logger.error(Logger.java:229)
```

Comment: It would seem that this is simply being out of stack space. [This page discusses better parameters](https://community.igniterealtime.org/thread/48569) - have you recently had a JVM update? - and [this Q&A backs it up](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12529576/1270789). It's not quite enough to mark as a dup, as it probably depends a lot on your environment, but if you come up with a solution, please answer your own question to perhaps help others later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It normally indicates an issue with your script, i.e. endless recursion, cyclic regular expression or whatever so my suggestions are:

1. Double check your script consistency, i.e. run it with 1-2 users with View Results Tree listener enabled to make sure it does what it is supposed to do.
2. [Increase Java stack size](https://javatutorial.net/java-increase-memory) via `-Xss4` JVM argument.
3. Make sure you are following recommendations from [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure) guide, at least basic ones such as:

   - Run your test in non-GUI mode
   - Increase JVM Heap space for JMeter
   - Disable all the listeners during test execution

Comment: Thanks for your answer I really appreciate it. However:
1. Might be the actual reason but I'm not sure how I could go about debugging that stuff.
2. Tried that just now but it didn't seem to help
3. It's a stack-overflow not an out-of-memory issue so I'm not sure that would help. In any case, I've run it in non-GUI mode and I disabled all my listeners anyway.

Comment: Turns out the issue was something with the if-controllers I had inside my test plan not working properly